# What is the difference between int() and floor() in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

In Python 2, `floor()` returned a float value. Although not obvious to me, I found a few explanations clarifying  why it may be useful to have `floor()` return float (for cases like `float('inf')` and `float('nan')`).

However, in Python 3, `floor()` returns integer (and returns overflow error for the special cases mentioned before).

So what is the difference, if any, between `int()` and `floor()` now?

Comment: in short, `floor()` is the [mathematical floor `⌊⌋` function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) and `int()` is equivalent to `sgn(x)⌊|x|⌋` in math

Comment: By `floor`, probably `math.floor` is meant.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

`floor()` rounds *down*. `int()` *truncates*. The difference is clear when you use negative numbers:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.floor(-3.5)
-4
>>> int(-3.5)
-3
```

Rounding down on negative numbers means that they move away from 0, truncating moves them closer to 0.

Putting it differently, the `floor()` is always going to be lower or equal to the original. `int()` is going to be closer to zero or equal.

Answer (score 18):

I tested the time complexity of both methods, they are the same.

```py
from time import time
import math
import random

r = 10000000
def floorTimeFunction():
    for i in range(r):
        math.floor(random.randint(-100,100))

def intTimeFunction():
    for i in range(r):
        int(random.randint(-100,100))

t0 = time()
floorTimeFunction()
t1 = time()
intTimeFunction()
t2 = time()

print('function floor takes %f' %(t1-t0))
print('function int     takes %f' %(t2-t1))
```

Output is:

```
# function floor takes 11.841985
# function int   takes 11.841325
```

Answer (score 5):

Rounding down can be done in many ways, some methods are equivalent, e.g. built-in `int`, `numpy.trunc` and `numpy.fix` which truncate the number, meaning for a negative number they return a result which is larger than the argument. `floor` is different and actually returns the next smaller integer regardless of the sign. This can be confusing. Here is a summary of built-in and numpy operators:

```
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
         ROUNDING -2.8 -2.5 -2.2  2.2  2.5  2.8
┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
            floor   -3   -3   -3    2    2    2
             rint   -3   -2   -2    2    2    3
        round (0)   -3   -2   -2    2    2    3
              fix   -2   -2   -2    2    2    2
            (int)   -2   -2   -2    2    2    2
            trunc   -2   -2   -2    2    2    2
             ceil   -2   -2   -2    3    3    3
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
```

Comment: Interesting post but it would be much clearer if the columns with integers were removed as it is quite intuitive that all functions treat them equally.

Comment: @GianlucaMicchi: Right, thanks. Updating. This table was actually one of a set where integer values are not processed the same way by other functions (e.g. `divmod` remainder vs `fmod` when the divisor is negative).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this method, does the trick for me,

```
def rightInteger(numa, numb):
    result = numa/numb
    next_int = math.ceil(result)
    difference = next_int -result
    if(difference <=0.5):
        return next_int
    else:
        return math.floor(result)
```

Comment: that is fully equivalent to `round()` except that it rounds up at exactly X.5