# Are int() and floor() interchangeable?

Tags: python, int, floor

`int(7.5)` and `floor(7.5)` both return `7` because the former truncates decimals and the latter rounds them down. Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: it has been explained in details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036098/what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-floor-in-python-3

Comment: Note also that `round(7.5)` and `round(8.5)` both return 8. But the documentation is quite clear on these things; read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For positive numbers, truncating at the decimal point and rounding down have the same effect. For negative numbers though, `int()` returns a number one greater than `floor()`

```
int(-7.5) == -7  # True
floor(-7.5) == -8  # True
```